# How to prove inverse metric is a metric in Y

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I just need to know if my answer is right based on the following question:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism of $X$ onto a topological space $Y$. Define a metric $p$ in $Y$ as $p(p,q)=d(f^{-1}(p),f^{-1}(q))$ prove $p$ is a metric in $Y$.

this is what I tried:

1) $d'(p,q)=d(f^{-1}(p),f^{-1}(q)) (\Rightarrow ) 0 \text{ b/c } d(p,q)(\Rightarrow)0$

2) $d'(p,q)=d(f^{-1}(p),f^{-1}(q))=0 \text{ iff } d(p,q)=0. \text{ since $d$ is metric in $X$}, \, d(p,q)=0 \text{ iff } p=q.$ Thertefore, $d'(p,q)=0 \text{ iff } p=q$

3) since d is metric, $d(p,q)=d(q,p)$. so 
$$d'(p,q)=d(f^{-1}(p),f^{-1})=d(f^{-1}(q),f^{-1}(p)=d'(q,p)$$

4) since d is metric, $d(p,q) (\Leftarrow) d(p,r)+d(r,q)$ so $d'(p,q)=d(p,q) (\Leftarrow) d(p,r)+d(r,q) (\Leftarrow) d'(p,r)+d'(r,q)$ so $d'(p,q)(\Leftarrow)d'(p,r)+d'(r,q)$

Comment: This sort of question is called axiom bashing and should be something you can and should try to do on your own.  Show what you have tried and then people can give some helpful pointers

Comment: I tried 1)d'(p,q)=d(f^(-1)(p),f^(-1)(q)(=>)0 b/c d(p,q)(=>)0  2)d'(p,q)=d(f^(-1)(p),f^(-1)(q))=0 iff d(p,q)=0. since d is metric in X, d(p,q)=0 iff p=q. Thertefore d'(p,q)=0 iff p=q    3)since d is metric, d(p,q)=d(q,p). so d'(p,q)=d(f^(-1)(p),f^(-1)=d(f^(-1)(q),f^(-1)(p)=d'(q,p)     4) since d is metric, d(p,q) (<=) d(p,r)+d(r,q) so d'(p,q)=d(p,q)(<=) d(p,r)+d(r,q) (<=)d'(p,r)+d'(r,q) so d'(p,q)(<=)d'(p,r)+d'(r,q)

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the same letter $p$ for the metric and for a point in $Y$ (as in the first paragraph of the question).

Comment: it is supposed to be the greek symbol but I don't know how to put it in that way on the computer.....I just need to know if I am answering it right and what I am doing wrong. I put up what I have after people asked me for it but I have no idea if it is right

Comment: You probably mean $\rho$, which is entered as `$\rho$`. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Just go through the axioms in the [definition of a metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition):

So you check for example that for $x = f^{-1}(y)$
$$
p(y,y) = d(f^{-1}(y), f^{-1}(y)) = d(x,x) \geq 0.
$$
And for example if $x_1 = f^{-1}(y_1)$ and $x_2 = f^{-1}(y_2)$ you have
$$
p(y_1, y_2) = 0 \Leftrightarrow d(f^{-1}(y_1), f^{-1}(y_2)) = 0 \Leftrightarrow d(x_1, x_2) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_1 = x_2 \Rightarrow y_1 = f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y_2.
$$
(if $y_1 = y_2$ you obviously have $p(y_1, y_2) = 0)$.

Comment: It is useful to notice that nothing about the topology on $Y$ is needed here, you just need that $Y$ is a bijection. (Maybe there is a follow-up of this exercise, which asks to prove that the topology induced by this metric is precisely the topology of $Y$.)